# Error deploying Spring with JAX-WS application in Jboss 6 server

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, web-services, springframework

I'm getting the following error when deploying a Spring+JAX-WS application on JBoss server 6.1.0:

```
09:14:38,175 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) [:2.5.6]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_05]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45) [:2.5.6]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_05]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_05]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_05]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [:1.7.0_05]
at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at $Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)   at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.actions.DeploymentStartAction.doPrepare(DeploymentStartAction.java:98) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:101) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.plugins.deploy.AbstractDeployHandler.startDeployments(AbstractDeployHandler.java:168) [:0.2.2]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandlerDelegate.startDeployments(DeployHandlerDelegate.java:74) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.profileservice.management.upload.remoting.DeployHandler.invoke(DeployHandler.java:156) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:967) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:548) [:6.1.0.Final]
at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234) [:6.1.0.Final]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127) [:2.5.6]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_05]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:98) [:2.5.6]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:223) [:2.5.6]
... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader 
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:263) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:65) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:133) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:85) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:156) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:93) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:473) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:319) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1170) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:188) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:111) [:2.2]
at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:113) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:159) [:2.2.3]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.7.0_05]
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:158) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:99) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:250) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:343) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:205) [:2.2.3]
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:513) [:2.2.3]
at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:333) [:]
at org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService.getObject(SpringService.java:45) [:]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport$1.run(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:121) [:2.5.6]
... 93 more



*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error

vfs:///usr/jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/SpringWS.war -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/usr/jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automountb159aa6e8c1b8582/SpringWS.war-4ec4d0151b4c7d7/ deployment failed

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
Deployment "vfs:///usr/jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/SpringWS.war" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/usr/jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs/automountb159aa6e8c1b8582/SpringWS.war-4ec4d0151b4c7d7/ deployment failed
```

But this application is working correctly in GlassFish 3.x server and the web service is up and running.

I'm using the Netbeans IDE on Ubuntu 12.04 to build and deploy the application and I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

I guess it has something to do with Spring and JBoss because it's working in GlassFish smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some research, I found the solution for this error. I have removed following jars from the `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

- jaxen-1.1-beta-9
- stax-api-1.0.1
- stax-api-1.0-2
- stax-utils-20040917
- wsdl4j-1.6.1
- xbean-2.2.0
- xercesImpl
- xmlParserAPIs-2.2.6.2
- XmlSchema-1.1